# Is there a way to programmatically enable or disable the Internet Sharing in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

In OSX I can enable or disable Internet Sharing by opening "System Preferences", then clicking on the "Sharing" pane, and finally checking (or unchecking) the "Internet sharing" checkbox.

I was wondering whether the OS offer a API for doing this operation from Objective-C (or command line). I'm looking in this apple [site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/) but I haven't found nothing for now.

Also suggestion on where looking for would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a perfect solution to this issue, because the System Preferences 'Sharing' pane actually does some extra work to make sure all required network settings are changed appropriately, but the partial answer is to run

`sudo launchctl [load|unload] -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist`

after first setting up which interface to share with which in the `Sharing` pane. Hope this helps!

(If you're curious and ambitious, the Internet Sharing binary lives (in recent OS Xes) at `/usr/libexec/InternetSharing`, and running that with the `--help` option gives some sparse feedback. Good luck!)